# While finding sum of binomial coefficients,why or how can we change index of Σ?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

[image]

Like here, how and why did we change it? When can we change this, when can’t we change the index cause I know it matters?
I have seen many examples now and have no source of information regarding this

Comment: Index like 0 to 1

Comment: Try rewriting both sums, you will see that they are exactly the same. They are just using a 'different' dummy variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood it correctly, the confusion you are having is how to write 
$$\sum_{r = 0}^{n}r \,^{n}C_{r} = n \sum_{r = 1}^{n}\,^{n-1}C_{r-1}.$$

The proof is here:

\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 0}^{n}r \, ^{n}C_{r} & = \underbrace{0 \cdot \,^{n}C_{0}}_{=\, 0} + 1 \cdot \,^{n}C_{1} + \cdots + n \cdot \,^{n}C_{n} \\
& = 1 \cdot \,^{n}C_{1} + \cdots + n \cdot \,^{n}C_{n} = \sum_{r = 1}^{n}r\,^{n}C_{r}  \\
& =  \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \left[r \times \dfrac{n!}{(n-r)! \, r!} \right]  = \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \left[r \times \dfrac{n \times (n-1)!}{(n-r)! \times \, r \times (r-1)!} \right]\\
& = n \left[ \sum_{r = 1}^{n}\dfrac{(n-1)!}{((n-1) - (r-1))!\,(r-1)!}\right] \\
& = n \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \, ^{n-1}C_{r-1}
\end{align}

Comment: You understood what I was asking:)

Comment: Please accept the answer if you're satisfied! @AshishRajShukla